# How to connect to multiple bluetooth sensors to a device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, iot, spp

I have multiple bluetooth sensors (20+) that I need to connect to whatever central device(PC, Phone, ...) via Bluetooth to collect the transmitted data.

I need to keep the connections active with the sensors because it is broadcasting data 20 times/second.

I already thought about using RaspberryPi to setup a Master-Slave pattern and enable multi Bluetooth connections, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant and simple way to do this.

The only objective is to collect the data simultaneously from the sensors. I have a no limitation for the "collector device" for the technology.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get it done? I need to do the same would you please help?

Comment: Still no solution.. I'm working on it